# Error:null value in entry: streamOutputFolder=null OR Error:null value in entry: streamOutputFolder=null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am unable to run my `app` in `emulator` because of this `Error`:

> `Error:null value in entry: streamOutputFolder=null`

or

> `gradle - Error:null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null`

Answer (score 1):

When you are unable to run your app on your emulator or phone

go to the .gradle folder delete it then rebuild your projects
then click on run button

if that doesnt work
delete .gradle folder
open the `build.gradle` file
which content something like this

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

//change the classpath to

classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`

but if your classpath initially is `2.3.1` change it to `2.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

```
Empty all "build" folders in your project
Copy all your project files and folders
Create a new folder and past it there
Open android Studio and import project
Wait Android Studio to download all dependecies.
```

And i found another solution here: [LINK](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/null-value-in-entry-dependencycachedir-null/19191)

- Removing the .gradle directory in the root project directory will fix the problem.

Hope this helps you.